# Is there any tool to go through the contents of clipboard?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, clipboard

I want to go through its contents of the clipboard, in hex mode if necessary, depending on the content.

Is there any tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows xp has the "Clipboard Viewer"... that comes with windows... but above that, you'll have to revert to using 3rd party tools that you can easily find using [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=clipboard+viewer).